# How to automatically trigger URL visit of a WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, bots

I have a WordPress website that is hosted on an Ionos shared server. For some reason, the 1st connection to the website is extremely slow (> 50s), and all the connections (within 1-2h) that follow are fast.

The phenomena appears:

- Even if I do the first connection to the website using my phone 4G (that will be really long) and then the second connection with my laptop (that will be normally fast).
- Whether or not I have my WordPress cache plugin activated.

I am currently trying to understand what could cause the issue and try different other things (increase host performance contract, move website to another host, etc.) but in the meantime, I was wondering if **there would be an easy way to use a script or something to automatically visit my website every 15 min for example. Not as a long-term solution but as a temporary one while I understand the root cause.** That would give me time considering that this is for a website that is already online and working.

Ideally, it should be something that could run on the server and not on my personal laptop.

Hope I am clear.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wget` or `curl` to initiate connection to your site. Add in `cron` something like:

```
*/15 * * * * wget http://example.com/path
```

and this will call your site every 15 minutes